# Embed plotly diagram in html document from orgmode

Tags: python, emacs, plotly, org-mode

I have a python script inside a orgmode document that creates a diagram with plotly (which works fine). Now I want the results block to show the diagram on html export. Here is my example document:

```
#+title: test with plotly in org
#+author: Thats Me
#+html_head: <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

* My Chapter
Python code with plotly here.
#+begin_src python
  import plotly.express as px

  fig = px.line(x=[0,1,2,3,4], y=[0,1,4,9,16])
  fig.show()
  fig.write_html("out.html", include_plotlyjs=True, full_html=True)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: None

[[file:out.html]]

#+include: out.html html
```

The link is unfortunately only a clickable link, which leads to the file (and if the arguments include_plotlyjs and full_html are set properly, will be displayed correctly). But I would like to see the diagram directly below the text.

With the include command I unfortunately only get a text output and not the diagram. Also it comes to an error message "Unable to resolve link: "0"" when the argument include_plotlyjs=True is set.

What is your approach to export plotly graphics from orgmode documents into html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who are trying the same thing, I have found a solution after much trial and error:

```
#+begin_src python :results raw html :exports both
  import plotly.offline as pyo
  import plotly.graph_objs as go

  trace = go.Scatter(x=[0,1,2,3,4], y=[0,1,4,9,16])
  fig = go.Figure(data=[trace])
  fig_html = pyo.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=True, output_type='div')
  return fig_html.encode()
#+end_src
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To execute code in a browser I think it is preferable to use JavaScript instead of Python.

Just put the code below in an org file and do `C-c C-e ho` (this example is taken from [this page](https://plotly.com/javascript/getting-started/)).

```js
#+title: Test with plotly in org
#+author: Thats Me

* My Chapter
JS code with plotly here.
#+begin_export html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
<script>
    TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
    Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [{
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16] }], {
    margin: { t: 0 } } );
</script>
#+end_export
```